# How to extract year, month or day from BIGINT epoch timestamp when inserting in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, epoch

I would like to extract a date format like month, year or day from a BIGINT timestamp `1543258003796` in the Redshift SQL environment when inserting data into a table.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE time_table (
    month_date    character varying(20),
    year_date     character varying(20),
);
```

Now I want to populate the table `time_table` with data from another table `ts_table` that has a column with timestamp as BIGINT type:

```
INSERT INTO time_table (month_date, year_date)
SELECT EXTRACT(month from ts.timestamp) as month_date,
       EXTRACT(year from ts.timestamp)  as year_date
FROM ts_table ts;
```

It raises an error because `ts.timestamp` is a BIGINT. Should I first cast the BIGINT into something else? Or is there another function to perform this action? I tried several things but I am still not able to find a solution.

Comment: 1) You should be storing timestamps as `timestamptz` not as `bigint`. 2) The docs are your friend [Date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html): `to_timestamp ( double precision ) → timestamp with time zone`

Comment: Forgot Redshift is not one to one compatible with Postgres. Turns out the form for `to_timestamp()` I showed does not exist in Redshift. You will need to use @BillWeiner answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that these BIGINT dates are epoch dates. So you first need to convert this to a timestamp - for example like so:

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + t.timestamp * interval '1 second' AS timest
from ts_table t;
```

Now this isn't want you want but it gets you into a timestamp data type and opens up the useful functions available to you.

Step 2 is to EXTRACT the year and month from this.  Putting these together you get:

```
WITH ts_conv as (
  select timestamp 'epoch' + t.timestamp * interval '1 second' AS 
  timest
  from ts_table t
)
SELECT EXTRACT(month from ts.timest) as month_date,
       EXTRACT(year from ts.timest)  as year_date
FROM ts_conv ts;
```

And this of course can be inside your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. My problem was that I didn't search for my problem properly. The problem was that I wasn't looking for a solution for the EPOCH timestamp. Now it is solved!